# How to display image in Laravel in view?

Tags: php, laravel

```
    if ($request->hasfile('image','sign')) {
        $file = $request->file('image','sign');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
        $filename = time() . '.' . $extension;
        $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/employee/');
        $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

        $insert->image = $filename;
        $insert->sign = $filename;

    } else {

        $insert->sign = '';
      $insert->image = '';
    }
   $insert->save();
```

this is my code Data not being saved in database too.so please help me.and i want to display image in the view.

Answer (score 3):

1. First, check whether the uploaded file available in the request or not. print ***$request->all()*** in your controller.
2. Please share your form code also.

Can you please try this?

```
if ($request->hasfile('image')) { 
    //print_r('Coming'); 
    $file = $request->file('image'); 
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();  
    $filename = time() . '.' . $extension;  
    $destinationPath = public_path(). '/uploads/employee/'; //here changed the path syntax. 
    $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);  
    // File::isDirectory($destinationPath) or File::makeDirector($destinationPath, 0777, true, true);  
    $insert->image = $filename; 
    $insert->sign = $filename;  
} else {
    $insert->sign = '';
    $insert->image = '';
} 
$insert->save();
```

**Sample code from my project - Multiple images upload**

```
if ($item->save()) {
    $options = $request->get('options');
    foreach ($options as $i => $option) {
        $file = $request->file('options')[$i]['image'];
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $destination = public_path().'/uploads';
        File::isDirectory($destination) or File::makeDirectory($destination, 0777, true, true);
        $file->move($destination, $name);

        ItemChoice::create([
            'item_id' => $item->id,
            'title' => $option['choice_title'],
            'description' => $option['choice_description'],
            'url' => $option['choice_url'],
            'image' => $name
         ]);
    }
}
```